# How to make Fake phone call in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

Any one knows about Implement Fake Receiving Phone Call[Fake Receiving Phone Call]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just code for fake call

1. It will work only when app is open
2. Add image incoming call image to full view. **(In order to make more attractive use UIImageViewAnimation to animate slide to answer)**

   UIImageView *callImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
   [[self view] addSubview:callImageView];

[image]

3. Play ringtone using using AVAudioPlayer

Comment: Nice, but how to make like this when app is close state

Comment: That's not possible, as much as you can set reminder and then you can open app on reminder alert.

Comment: I Can't Vote For this reason --->"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: No Problem Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you abhishek

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to user Third party service like twilio who will initiate a real call to the phone.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code for phone call:

```
NSString *StrPhone = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt://%@", PhoneNumber];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:StrPhone];
        [[UIApplication  sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```